# Domains of holomorphy in the complex plane

Tags: cv.complex-variables

There is a proof of [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_theorem) with an explicit construction of a holomorphic function with the prescribed poles with prescribed order and residues, for a countable discrete set of points. I do not remember the reference; but my memory from my graduate course is that one defines a series sum and make certain adjustments. I was never quite good in this type of processes; so I am facing problem with the following exercise, which is nagging me for a long time. I thought of using Math Overflow with the hope that somebody can help me out.

Now I want to prove that every open set in the complex plane is now a [domain of holomorphy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_theorem). We take the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of the open set $\Omega$, and we take a countable dense sequence of points $z_i$ in $\partial \Omega$. If we are able to construct a series sum with poles at $z_i$, but so that it converges absolutely and uniformly on every compact set in the interior of $\Omega$, then we are done.

I would be most grateful if somebody can show me how to do the above.

Comment: 
 You have to assume the discrete set of points is CLOSED in Mittag-Leffler's theorem (Wikipedia erroneously forgets this condition ). For example it is impossible to find a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ with principal part equal to $1/(z−1/n)$  at $1/n$ , although the set of $1/n$'s in $\mathbb C$ is certainly discrete. By the way Mittag-Leffler's construction yields a meromorphic function, not a holomorphic one, and  the prescription is principal parts, not residues.

Comment: You probably want to assume the open set is *connected*.  Otherwise, a locally analytic function whose domain is not connected is by convention generally not thought of a a single analytic function. (Even when it is everywhere defined by a single series, such as in Josh Shadlen's elegant answer below.)

Such a function can, for instance, violate the permanence principle.

There are some fascinating examples of such functions in Hille's Analytic Function Theory, vol. II.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\zeta_k$ be a countable dense sequence of points in the boundary and consider $f(z) = \sum \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{1}{z-\zeta_k}$. The sum is plainly uniformly convergent on any subset of finite distance from the boundary, in particular on any compact subset of the interior.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than trying to put the poles *on* the boundary, choose a countable discrete subset $D = \{z_n\}$ of $\Omega$ whose closure contains $\partial \Omega$ (first convince yourself this is always possible) and then apply Mittag-Leffler's theorem to get a holomorphic function $f$ on $\Omega$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f(z_n)| = \infty$.  Then show that this does what you want.

**Addendum**: I found a reference for the interpolation result I was using.

Theorem (Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis*, Theorem 15.13): Let $\Omega$ be an open set in the complex 
plane and $A$ a closed, discrete subset of $\Omega$.  To each $\alpha \in A$ we associate 
a non-negative integer $m(\alpha)$ and complex numbers $w_{\alpha,i}$ for $0 \leq i \leq m(\alpha)$.  Then there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on $\Omega$ such that for all 
$\alpha \in A$ and all $0 \leq i \leq m(\alpha)$, $f^{(i)}(\alpha) = w_{\alpha,i}$.

This theorem -- and other variants involving meromorphic functions -- is indeed due to Gosta Mittag-Leffler and is often called the **Anschmiegungssatz**.

Comment: Pete, I have upvoted this construction but I think you have to apply an interpolation theorem for functions defined on the $z_n$'s  and not  Mittag-Leffler's theorem *stricto sensu* if you want  f to be holomorphic at the $z_n$'s (but maybe I'm missing some subtlety).

Comment: @Georges -- you're right. I am using an interpolation theorem which is reminiscent of Weierstrass Factorization and Mittag-Leffler but not identical to either one. In fact the special case of $\mathbb{C}$ has been asked several times on MO, most recently by Kevin Buzzard. Offhand, I don't have a reference for the general case...sorry!

Comment: @Georges -- the theorem is the following. You can construct an analytic function on a domain with prescribed isolated values on a countable set of isolated points. The proof goes along the same lines as that of Mittag-Leffler's theorem. 